# Qty on hand filter missmatch

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have this 2 product that shown in the first picture, and they have "Qty on hand" is zero

[image]

after that, I go to advanced filter and filter by "Qty on hand' = 0.0, and now this 2 product disappear.

[image]

this method is responsible for the search and i can't figure out why is he working not correctly.

```py
 def _search_product_quantity(self, cr, uid, obj, name, domain, context):
        prod = self.pool.get("product.product")
        product_variant_ids = prod.search(cr, uid, domain, context=context)
        return [('product_variant_ids', 'in', product_variant_ids)]
```

this method is from the original Odoo module you can find it in stock/product.py line 376.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2jMR.jpg already work i am checked with odoo9.0

Comment: When Product have any variants at that time it can't consider On Hand quantity of product template.